# Denormalize data for purchased items

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
BoughtItems 

UserID  ItemID  StoreID  Quantity  Price
1       1       1        1         1
1       4       1        2         3
1       5       2        1         3
```

Let's assume that it will be no more then five items for each user in `BoughtItems` table.

I want to have all the clients from some StoreID and all items that were purchased, in this format... for StoreID = 1 the result will be:

```
UserID  Item1ID  Item2ID  Item3ID  Item4ID  Item5ID
1       1        4        [empty]  [empty]  [empty]
```

Comment: How is the Stores table relevant?

Comment: Also, if someone has only bought three items, what do you want in the result? Instead of a word problem, can you show sample data, desired results, and whether those results are just returned from a query or if you really need to redundantly store this data in another table this way (and explain why)?

Comment: I want the specified result table for some `StoreID`. Stores table has relation on StoreID field in BoughtItems

Comment: I don't know what "specified result table" means. Are you trying to run a query and return results, or are you trying to store the data in a new table? And could you please indicate what version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, and specified result table means the table which should be returned by the query.

Comment: Okay, well just to prevent confusion in the future, the result of a query is not a table.

Comment: @Randy PIVOT won't help much here, I think, unless you know all of the potential values for `ItemID`. If you know otherwise, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StoreID INT;

SET @StoreID = 1;

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT UserID, ItemID, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ItemID)
  FROM dbo.BoughtItems
  WHERE StoreID = @StoreID
)
SELECT UserID,
    Item1ID = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ItemID END),
    Item2ID = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ItemID END),
    Item3ID = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ItemID END),
    Item4ID = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN ItemID END),
    Item5ID = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN ItemID END)
FROM x WHERE rn <= 5
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: Thanks, this query works. But as I can see in my case it's better to create one table with all fields.

Comment: @seeker still not sure if you're talking about a table or the result of a query. <shrug>